# callback not working on android device codenameone

Tags: codenameone

My connection request has a callback which works perfectly in the simulator but not on my android device.
Can anyone help me understand what is happening

I have already set this permission to allow network access
android.xapplication_attr = android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

public class MyConnectionRequest2 extends ConnectionRequest {

```
Map<String, Object> response = null;

ResponseModel returnValue;
public SuccessCallback scall;
public FailureCallback fcall;

public MyConnectionRequest2(Callback call) {
    super();
    this.fcall = call;
    this.scall = call;
    setFailSilently(true);
}

public Map<String, Object> getResponse() {
    return response;
}

@Override
protected void postResponse() {
    if (scall != null) {
        scall.onSucess(returnValue);
    }
}

@Override
protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
    if (fcall != null) {
        fcall.onError(this, null, code, message);
    }
}

@Override
protected void handleException(Exception err) {
    if (fcall != null) {
        fcall.onError(this, err, -1, null);
    }
}

@Override
protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
    if (input != null) {
        JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
        Map<String, Object> response = parse.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
        if (response != null && response.size() > 0) {
            ResponseModel status = new ResponseModel();
            status.setRecordId((response.get("recordId") == null) ? "" : response.get("recordId").toString());
            status.setSuccess((response.get("success") == null) ? false : response.get("success").equals("true"));
            status.setMessage((response.get("message") == null) ? "" : response.get("message").toString());
            status.setEntity((response.get("entity") == null) ? "" : response.get("entity").toString());
            status.setOperation((response.get("operation") == null) ? "" : response.get("operation").toString());
            returnValue = status;
        } else {
            returnValue = new ResponseModel("", false, "Error", "payment", "confirm");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Which callback request?
Can you include some code?

Comment: just realised the connection was timing out ...how do i extend the timeout for android

Comment: To set the timeout use ConnectionRequest.setTimeout() and/or ConnectionRequest.setReadTimeout().  https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/ConnectionRequest.html#setTimeout-int-